# Android alert dialog good usage

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I couldn't find anything usefull on the internet about my problem. So my question is how do you do a good usage of Android's alert dialogs. Here is an example of code creating and showing an alert dialog just with the title "error", the text "you can't do that" and a "Ok" button :

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You can't do that");
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
            getResources().getString("ok"),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    alertDialogError = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialogError.show();
```

But now, if I have many of this alert dialogs in my application, what should I do ?

Should I set the alertDialogBuilder as an attribute so each time I want to display an error message I can call his function setMessage() and then create() and then show() ?

Should I keep an already configured alertDialog for every single error message I have so I can just call theRightAlertDialog.show() to display my message ?

Something else ?

What's the good usage/cleanest way to do this for you ?

Comment: reusing the builder seems kind of overkill. just create a new builder and dialog every time you need to show a dialog. if you get into a situation that makes obvious sense to reuse the builder, then do it.  it's not really "dirty" or "unclean" to simply just create builders as needed

Answer (score 2):

You could do this one of two ways. The first is to create a static method, which you can place in a `final` utility class:

```
public final class AlertUtil {

    public static void showErrorDialog(Context context, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(
                getResources().getString("ok"),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Or you can use a [`DialogFragment`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) which you can create with:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(ErrorDialogFragment.newInstance(message), "tag").commit()`
```

---

I will say though, as a side note; if you are looking to change more than just a few fields for each of the dialogs (i.e. adding more parameters to the `showErrorDialog` method), then you probably should just stick to the `Builder` pattern. Considering that *is* what the `Builder` pattern is meant for.

Comment: The last two lines are not correct, rather put `builder.create().show();`. Just a typo. Thanks so much though, this is great.

Comment: @trevren Actually, you can just call `builder.show()` if you don't want a reference to the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I set the alertDialogBuilder as an attribute so each time I want to display an error message I can call his function setMessage() and then create() and then show() ?

If the title and the button functionality are the same for all of your alerts, than this would be the best strategy. Create a variable for the alertDialogBuilder, or even just the alertDialog itself, then change the message and show it each time.

Alternatively, you could create a method that builds the dialog, and takes in a string for the message text.